# converting file to array and adding array elements for auto complete text box using datalist and option tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
     <input type="text" list="anrede" />
<datalist id="anrede"></datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var options='';
function readTextFile()
{

    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "file:///D:/search.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText; 
                <!--allText array contains file elements inception force batman superman supergirl-->
                    var arr=allText.split("\n");
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                    {

                        options += '<option value="'+arr[i]+'" />'; <!-- trying to add array elements for auto completion -->

                    }
                 document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;

            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);

}
    readTextFile();

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

search.txt contains:
inception
force
batman
superman
supergirl

it is showing "null" at the end of elements in the result of auto completion when inputted in the text box.how to remove that??

Comment: You're using HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) inside JavaScript. Use the `//` notation and you will probably find your code works in far more places. Also, are you sure that `rawFile.responseText` is actually returning an array?

Comment: converting file to array elements is correct, but after that in datalist and option tags ,i am getting wrong output and both programs "conversion from file to array" and "displaying array elements using datalist/option tag for autocompletion" are working right separately.

Comment: rawFile.responseText is returning array correctly. i checked by displaying as:   document.write(allText[i])    inside loop.

Comment: comments are added after execution before posting here...

Comment: It works correctly for me assuming the array is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/eqf8aahd/ I think your `rawFile.responseText;` is returning just a string, you will need to turn it in to an array. (Try changing your check to `document.write(allText[i] + "<br />") ` to check wether you're getting each letter or each element)

Comment: DBS you were right, its returning string actually.so now i converted it into array,  var arr=allText.split("\n");

Comment: but now its showing null at the end of elements in result.how to remove them???

Comment: `var arr=allText.trim().split("\n");` Will trim any extra white space off beginning and end of the string before turning it into an array. If there are multiple line breaks, you could iterate over your array removing null values.

Comment: i have edited the code above.can u check it why null is coming at the end?i tried trim() and cleaning already but still the problem sustained...

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood what you meant, I've added an answer which should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
     <input type="text" list="anrede" />
<datalist id="anrede"></datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var options='';
function readTextFile()
{

    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "file:///D:/search.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText; 
                //allText.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, "")
                var arr=allText.trim().split("\n");
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                    {
                        console.log(arr[i]);
       options+='<optionvalue="'+arr[i].replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, "")+'">';

                    }
                 document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;

            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);

}
    readTextFile();

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to simply add a null check into your loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] !== null && arr[i].trim() !== ""){
        options += '<option value="' + arr[i] + '" />'; 
    }
}
```

This should prevent any blank options being added.